# Can I get my JWT after authenticating to any website?

Tags: oauth, jwt

Is the token returned by the server in a response? Can I fetch my JWT after successfully authenticating?

What I'm trying to understand, Can I:

1. Send POST request to authenticate to a certain website
2. Return my JWT for this session

Answer (score 1):

The token is returned in the`Authorization` response header. You can see more about it [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/)